# Unable to join two tables with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to join two tables and serialize them as an API. I have referred to the docs of the Django rest framework and tried a code. It didn't work. Could not resolve the problem even after trying so many times. I am trying to get a JSON file like

```
{
'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
'tracks': [
    {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement'},
    {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say'},
    {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore'},
    ...
  ],
}
```

But what I get is

```
{
'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
}
```

This is the model file I am using

**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



STATUS_CHOICE = (
    ('simple', 'simple'),
    ('intermediate', 'intermediate'),
)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    video_id = models.ForeignKey("youtube.Youtube",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questions_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    pass_mark = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.quiz_name

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default='simple')
    quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Questions(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    mark = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    choice_2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    choice_3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    choice_4 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=choice_1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

**Serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import  serializers
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated   
from .models import Category, Quiz, Questions, Choice
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = '__all__'

class QuestionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = '__all__'

class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = '__all__'

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quiz_name =  QuizSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id','category','quiz_name']
```

**View.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, mixins
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializer import CategorySerializer
from .models import Category


class ViewQuiz(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny,
    ]
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = CategorySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id','category','quiz_id']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
       response = super().to_representation(instance)
       response['quiz_id'] = QuizSerializer(instance.quiz_id).data
       return response
```

This will produce the result you want, I made an change in how the serializer represent the data. I have some of my serializer doing the same, but my views are working a bit different from yours.

Comment: gives an error "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `quiz_name` is not valid for model `Category`."

Comment: I made a edit, it's because your model Category doesn't have a field name `quiz_name`, I checked and the name is `quiz_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get questions serializes in quiz.
To do that you need to:
1. In `Questions` model include `related_name` in quiz field:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="questions")
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    mark = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

2. In `QuizSerializer` include `questions` field and set many to True:

```
class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionsSerializer(source="questions", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ("questions", ... other needed fields)
```

3. Include `source` attribute in `QuizSerializer` in `CategorySerializer`:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quiz_name = QuizSerializer(read_only=True, source="quiz_id")

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'quiz_name']
```

Your Quiz was not serialized because the relation between Category and Quiz in tables are called `quiz_id` but your field is called `quiz_name`, so the framework did not know where it should take quiz, because it was looking at `quiz_name` relation which does not exist.